# Error while working on chatbot-universal-sentence-encoder

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, tensorflow-hub

I am trying "chatbot.py" and I am getting below error.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "chatbot.py", line 11, in 
embeddings = model(df["MESSAGE"].values)["outputs"]
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

```
###########################
# chatbot.py starts here
from urllib import response
from utils import *
# pip install pandas
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# pip install openpyxl

model = embed_useT(r"C:/Users/Hp/Downloads/universal-sentence-encoder_4")
df = pd.read_excel("chats.xlsx")
print ('printing df', df)
embeddings = model(df["MESSAGE"].values)["outputs"]
norm = np.linalg.norm(embeddings, axis = -1)

def reply(message):
    message_vector = model([message])["outputs"]
    similarities = cos_similarity(message_vector, embeddings, norm)
    index = np.argmax(similarities)
    response = df["RESPONSE"].values[index]
    return response

while True:
    message = input("Type your message: ")
    response = reply(message)
    print (response)
# chatbot.py ends here
###########################

###########################
# utils.py starts here
import numpy as np
# pip install tensorflow-hub
import tensorflow_hub as hub 
# pip install tensorflow

# import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior()

def cos_similarity(vector, matrix, matrix_norm):
    dot = np.matmul(matrix, vector.T)
    vector_norm = np.linalg.norm(vector)
    norms = (vector_norm * matrix_norm); norms=norms.reshape(norms.shape[0],1)
    return dot / norms

def embed_useT(module):
    with tf.Graph().as_default():
        sentences = tf.placeholder(tf.string)
        embed = hub.KerasLayer(module)
        embeddings = embed(sentences)
        session = tf.train.MonitoredSession()
        return lambda x: session.run(embeddings, {sentences : x})
# utils.py ends here
###########################
```

chats.xlsx is as shown below

[image: chats.xlsx looks like this]

Answer (score 0):

`model(df["MESSAGE"].values)` already returns the embeddings as a numpy array. Omitting `["outputs"]` should make it work.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Could you please help? 
I changed line #11 
to 
embeddings = model(df["MESSAGE"].values)

and also line #15
to 
message_vector = model({message})

and it throws me an error as shown below
  File "C:\Users\chetan.chavan\Downloads\universal-sentence-encoder_4\chatbot.py", line 17, in reply
    message_vector = model({message})
  raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)  # pylint: disable=no-value-for-parameter
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Graph execution error: